# Firing an event when checkbox is checked for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, checkbox

What will be the correct way to get what are currently being checked in the `CheckBox`. What i have done so far will not firing any event on `CheckBox` items checked:

```
<ListBox Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding MachinePositionList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding posID}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CurrentCheckedPosition}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>                           
            </CheckBox>
       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Thanks a lot :-).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the checked events:

```
<CheckBox Name="myCheckBox" 
          Content="I am a checkbox!" 
          Checked="myCheckBox_Checked" 
          Unchecked="myCheckBox_Unchecked" />
```

And the code for these events is:

```
private void myCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}

private void myCheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

EDIT:
Just noticed you have the content for the checkboxes as "{Binding posID}" so something you can do (as you have a list of check boxes) is in the checked events, have something like:

```
if (sender != null)
{
     int posID = Convert.ToInt32(((CheckBox)sender).Name);
}
```

This will give you the "posID" and you can do what you need too with it. :D

Comment: this is a user control which do not attached to any view model.The view model will be assigned according to its parent. So is there any other way instead of trigger a routed event in the control itself? Thanks

Comment: You can still attach the event handlers, just do it through the code where you add the checkboxes. e.g tempCheckbox.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(myCheckbox_Checked);

Comment: Just to clarify, you are adding the checkboxes to the listview through another usercontrol/window?

Comment: the check box items being populated by the view model, and the view model will call this user control (contains said check box).

Comment: yes it is working. i'll pass the value to the user control text field and bind it over to my view model. is it the correct way to do that?