# How can I wtite my code behind for checkbox in MVVM?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a code for checkbox. Please tell me how to write it in MVVM?
There is a function that I can choose only one checkbox. In general I understand that I must to write command.

XAML:

```
    <StackLayout>
            <!-- Place new controls here -->
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox HorizontalOptions="Start" Color="Black" CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"
                                        IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                        />
                                <Label Text="meow" TextColor="Gray"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
     public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
            }
    
            Model previousModel;
            private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (previousModel != null)
                {
                    previousModel.IsSelected = false;
                }
                Model currentModel = ((CheckBox)sender).BindingContext as Model;
                previousModel = currentModel;
    
                if (currentModel.IsSelected)
                {
                    var viewModel = BindingContext as MainPageViewModel;
                    int index = viewModel.Items.IndexOf(currentModel);
                }
                
            }
    
            private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (previousModel != null)
                {
                    previousModel.IsSelected = false;
                }
                Model currentModel = e.SelectedItem as Model;
                currentModel.IsSelected = true;
                previousModel = currentModel;
            }
        }
```

ViewModel

```
        public class MainPageViewModel
        {
            public List<Model> Items { set; get; }
            public MainPageViewModel()
            {
                List<Model> list = new List<Model>();
                for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
                {
                    list.Add(new Model { IsSelected = false });
                }
                Items = list;
            }
        }
```

Model

```
        public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            bool isSelected;
            public bool IsSelected
            {
                set
                {
                    isSelected = value;
                    onPropertyChanged();
                }
                get => isSelected;
            }
    
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            void onPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930637/firing-an-event-when-checkbox-is-checked-for-wpf/14930759 This may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Take a look at using an [Event to Command behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/behaviors-eventtocommandbehavior/). It provides at reusable way to turn events like the CheckedChanged event into a command that can be hooked into from the viewmodel.

Comment: you should add `SelectedItem` property of type `Model`  to `MainPageViewModel` and bind to `ListView.SelectedItem` on change this property in VM(prolly in setter)  you should unset previously setted `IsSelected` (in setter this would be private field where you are storeing `SelectedItem` for VM fx `selectedItem`) and set current (`value.IsSelected` in setter) and set value (`selectedItem = value`) and prolly call OnPropChange... that's it

Answer (score 1):

For an event to command use Corcav.Behavior nuget
https://github.com/corradocavalli/Corcav.Behaviors

```
...
xmlns:corcav="clr-namespace:Corcav.Behaviors;assembly=Corcav.Behaviors"
...

<CheckBox>
         <corcav:Interaction.Behaviors>
                 <corcav:BehaviorCollection>
                        <corcav:EventToCommand EventName="CheckedChanged" Command="{Binding Path=CheckBoxChangedCommand}" Commandparameter="{Binding .}"/>
                 </corcav:BehaviorCollection>
          </corcav:Interaction.Behaviors>
</CheckBox>
```

Add this command in ViewModel and write your logic

```
public ICommand CheckBoxChangedCommand{ get; set; }
...
CheckBoxChangedCommand= new Command<object>(CheckBoxChanged);
...
private void CheckBoxChanged(object obj)
        {
    //set all list/collection element to false with linq
            if(obj is Model model)
            {
                model.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have error Error XLS0413 Could not find property "Commandparameter" on type "EventToCommand". If I write without Commandparameter I have error that is no available command

Comment: can you make a sample git repo that I can have a look into

Answer (score 0):

For now, CheckBox do not support Command. This issue has reported on Github and have not fixed. We could follow this enhancement. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6606

You could use the `InputKit` instead. Install `Xamarin.Forms.InputKit` on NuGet.
It provides `CheckChangedCommand`.

CheckChangedCommand: (Command) Bindable Command, executed when check changed.

```
 <input:CheckBox  HorizontalOptions="Start" Color="Black" CheckChangedCommand="{Binding CheckBoxChangedCommand}">
```